# How do I create an interior mesh for a vehicle

Tags: modeling, solidify-modifier

I am working on a plane for a mod and want to know: How can I create a separate interior mesh, basically making it a solid object. How can I do this without using the solidify modifier?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to:

- Go to Edit Mode
- Duplicate the mesh you want an interior for with Shift+D and press Right Click to apply.
- With the duplicated mesh selected, press Alt+S to evenly scale down the duplicated Mesh and right click to apply.
- Now press Shift+N to flip the face normals. Check/Uncheck the inside option for the desired result.
  [image]

Additionally you can enable 'Backface Culling' to visually see if the interior has the correct face orientation.

[image]

Also addtional you can enable face orientation for this. Red means backface, Blue means the correct front face.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however there is the problem of the separate mesh being visible through the windows.

Comment: Yea, you'll have to cut make the same holes for the interior mesh as well.